# Javascript, what does this line mean? "function myslide() { document.images.slideshow.src=eval("image"+numberImage+".src)"?

Tags: javascript

recently I am asked to make a website but I am not familiar with Javascript, is "document.images.slideshow.src" considered a path? what if I am to copy it to another computer? will it still work? I am worried that it will create a different path

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Way off topic to broad you need remedial tutorials and training

Comment: @JarrodRoberson can you please help me?

Comment: I think you need to go step by step. First figure out what does document.images give you then document.images.slideshow and ask the same question again. Please check what all scripts are there in the document and also please please please understand that Javascript is not like any other language. It works on browser and as long as the project is hosted on a server or the assets on the server the paths will still be the same

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal my script code is this but it's not working, can you help me? I am asked to make a slideshow: <img src="okdo1.jpg" name="slideshow" alt="imageslideshow">
<script type="text/javascript">
var numberImage = 1
function myslide() {
document.images.slideshow.src=eval("image"+numberImage+".src")
if(numberImage < 5 )
numberImage = numberImage + 1
else
numberImage = 1
setTimeout ("myslide()", 4500)
}
myslide()

</script>

Comment: I'd suggest first have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Then, understand how Javascript is changing the src tag here

Comment: `documet.imgaes` is a collection containing all the images on a page. `slideshow` is one of the images in the collection (there's `img id="slideshow"` on the page). `src` is the ... well, `src` of that image. `eval()` creates a path from a variable containing a reference to `img id="image0"`' (0 is just an example, might be something else too). Basicly the code just copies src of an existing image, and shows that same image in another `img` element.  The used computer doesn't matter, if you're creating a _webpage_, as you've told us.

Comment: I think to start off W3schools can be a good alternative

Comment: @Teemu. Thanks the answer is correct. you can put it in the answers section, but the OP needs to learn all this stuff first. We are not here to let them copy paste the code. We are here to try and make people understand how the stuff works.

Comment: @ErichTamio. Although the stuff here is explained now I'd vote for closure of this question due to its poor quality. But do not be upset about this since this is how every programmer starts his career in javascript. Best of luck for future. And please refer the rules about asking questions.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal I am sorry, and thank you for the help

Comment: @Teemu thank you so much for explaining!

Comment: Yes, Read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and the read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! This is not a basic tutorial site or a forum for discussion and hand holding. **Your question is way too broad because it is about extremely basic fundamental concepts that require a long format to understand.**

Answer (score 0):

`documet.imgaes` is a collection containing all the images on a page. `slideshow` is one of the images in the collection (there's `img id="slideshow"` on the page). `src` is the ... well, `src` of that image.

`eval()` creates a path from a variable containing a reference to `img id="image0"` (0 is just an example, might be something else too).

Basicly the code just copies `src` of an existing image, and shows that same image in another `img` element. The used computer doesn't matter, if you're creating a webpage, as you've told us.

Answer (score -1):

"function" - this line is part of a function definition

"myslide" - this is the name of the function

"()" - the function has no named arguments passed to it (it could still access passed values by the value array if i remember that part right.)

"document" - data structure containing the current web page, its parts, its elements, in a hierarchy

"images" - a̶̷r̶̷r̶̷a̶̷y̶̷ ̶̷o̶̷f̶̷ ̶̷i̶̷m̶̷a̶̷g̶̷e̶̷s̶̷  collection of images appended to the current document

"slideshow" - a particular image element in the current document I think (the current image in the slideshow I guess). The HTML for this would have ''

.src = - this is assigning a particular file to go into that HTML element
=eval("image"+numberImage+".src") - this is going to make a string like "image17.src" if numberImage is 17

The question has a typo.  The " marks are unbalanced. It would cause a javascript error I think.  Also I'm not sure why there's an "eval" there; it seems unnecessary.  If it needs to eval a variable called "src" (because images are usually called .gif or .jpg or .png) I don't know why it wouldn't do that directly, or construct the filename some other part of the code.

There should be an image called image17.src as I'm reading the question.

If your page is http://example.com/mypage.html then the image would be called as http://example.com/image17.src

The simplest way to make it work would be to have image17.src in the same directory as mypage.html on the server.  Also you could rig up the web server to look for ".src" in the URL and find those files in "/images/" inside your document root, but that would probably not be graceful or efficient.

Hope this helps - try to make your question more exact next time please, to focus on exactly the part you are wondering about, so other people can get benefit from it too.  If you are wondering about six things at once, try asking six questions. Write a list of them first.  We are busy people here!

Comment: A quick correction, `document.images` is not an array, it's a [collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Also it contains only images appended to a page, not all images in a document.

Comment: thank you for answering my question! I am still new here but now I understand, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm new here too, glad to help, (i wish you would accept it as best, because somehow I lost points by helping you with an answer.)